# Getting Start Date and End date of a Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Good day guys,

I have several reports generated using Crystal report with a Date Range value and I need to get the formular for the Start date and End date of the report

Several reports has been generated using Crystal Report. I have used the Minimum() and maximum() formulars to get the Start date of the range and also the end date of it. But it is only picking the start date for the two reports.

```
   minimum({Dttable.Order_date})
```

I expect the Output to be that if the date range selected is

```
01/07/2019-31/07/2019
```

Output should be start date `01/07/2019`
end date `31/07/2019`

Answer (score 0):

I got a way Around.

I had to use it as formular and not under RunningTotal